# How can I add dynamic button to Office Ribbon

Tags: c#, xml, ms-office, office-addins, ribbon

How can I add dynamic toggle button to Office Ribbon? Button names are dynamic, they can change, so how can I make the buttons dynamic?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All dynamism is possible for ribbon toggle buttons via callbacks. You can customize the Ribbon UI by using callback procedures in COM add-ins. For each of the callbacks that the add-in implements, the responses are cached. For example, if an add-in writer implements the `getImage` callback procedure for a button, the function is called once, the image loads, and then if the image needs to be updated, the cached image is used instead of recalling the procedure. This process remains in place until the add-in signals that the cached values are invalid by using the `Invalidate` method, at which time, the callback procedure is again called and the return response is cached. The add-in can then force an immediate update of the UI by calling the `Refresh` method. You can also find the [InvalidateControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.iribbonui.invalidatecontrol) method helpful which invalidates the cached value for a single control on the Ribbon user interface.

The `toggleButton` control has the `getPressed` callback which allows you to specify whether the toggle button control is pressed or not. It has the following signature:

```
C#: bool GetPressed(IRibbonControl control)

VBA: Sub GetPressed(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnValue)

C++: HRESULT GetPressed([in] IRibbonControl *pControl, [out, retval] VARIANT_BOOL *pvarfPressed)

Visual Basic: Function GetPressed(control As IRibbonControl) As Boolean
```

Read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: I want to add a dynamic toggle button to the ribbon.  ex: ribbon.Add(toggleButton1)

Comment: That's not possible. Instead, you may consider using the `dynamicMenu` control which allows adding buttons/items dynamically.